# How to maintain sequence of the values in a JSON object?

Tags: json, angular, ionic3, ionic-native, ionic-native-http

I am working on an ionic app which will be used on Android and iOS platforms. I am using one endpoint to post user data to the backend.

```
{
  "name": "abcd",
  "emailAddress": "abcd@def.com",
  "mobile": "1234567890"
}
```

when I send this JSON Object as above from ionic native HTTP it receives at backed like

```
{
      "name": "abcd",
      "mobile": "1234567890",
      "emailAddress": "abcd@def.com"

    }
```

as I am creating authorization signature using this information it causing an issue of unauthorized as the signature does not match at the backend. Is there any way to maintain the sequence of the JSON object? 
need some help here thanks!!

Comment: It's default nature of JSON. JSON is working on KVO, not like Array which maintain indexing.

Comment: can you show us your backend code?

Comment: can you send the data like an array of object like this 

[
 {
      "name": "abcd",
      "mobile": "1234567890",
      "emailAddress": "abcd@def.com"

  }
]

Comment: I have tried passing object inside the array, it did not work. @YashRami

Comment: can you show us the backend code

Comment: Try sending a base64 encoded string of your payload instead of the raw json object. Decoding on the server should provide the source object

Comment: `var rawContent = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
var stringContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var hash = md5.ComputeHash(rawContent);
var authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
if (authHeader != authorization)
    throw;`